# How to deselect a file from Quick Look list preview?

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

When you select multiple items and press space (open Quick Look) you can click an icon<sup>1</sup> where it shows a contact sheet with the thumbnails of the files, can you deselect an item without closing and reopening Quick Look?

I'm opening several files in Quick Look to compare them and I would like to deselect the items I no longer want, but closing and opening Quick Look and then reclicking on the thumbnails button is distracting and slow. Is there a way to do that?

<sup>1</sup>
6-boxes icon

[image]

Comment: You can de-select them the same way you selected - shift or cmd/click.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think they're asking how to deselect items from the quicklook UI. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULndM.png By clicking the 6 boxes-icon, Files' thumbnails appear. How to remove a file from there?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii - same answer applies, just deselect in the Finder. Even in thumbnail view it will change the selection live.

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh you mean shifting QL aside and then deselecting files in Finder window? yes it works :)

Comment: @ankiiiiiii - I tend to work in such a way as I can always see the folder I'm working from, before I go into QL.

Comment: The question is from Quick Look, not Finder. Full screen Quick Look occludes Finder

Comment: You never mentioned fullscreen at all - the answer is probably no, there's nothing you can do. Yet another reason [as if I ever needed another one] why I never ever use fullscreen :\